# Activate Checkstyle on Eclipse projects immediately after import

Tags: eclipse, maven, checkstyle

When using a newly imported Maven project in Eclipse (Oxygen 4.7.1a), I have to manually **Activate Checkstyle** on the project in order for Checkstyle to run whenever the project's build happens.

We can see in a newly imported project into Eclipse that its `.project` file does not contain any Checkstyle natures or build commands:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>test-parent</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

After selecting **Activate Checkstyle**, the build command and nature are added to the `.project`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>test-parent</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Is there any way to activate Checkstyle immediately upon import of the Maven project into Eclipse so that the `.project` will already have the build commands & natures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible as not implemented in the latest version of Maven Eclipse integration (m2e). See https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-dev/msg01783.html for more details.

Here people discussed how to hack this by writing an Eclipse Mojo that updates .project appropriately after the import: https://github.com/oasp/oasp4j-ide/issues/1 . But this is still not done by anybody I believe.